# Is it better to use column aliases with or without the keyword AS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, syntax

Which is best?

```
Select TestColumn TC
```

or

```
Select TestColumn AS TC
```

I prefer the first one but I am not sure if this is a modern way of declaring the alias.

Comment: See [Aaron Bertrand's very recent blog post on the topic](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) - he advocates using `SELECT SomeColumnName = ....... ` over both of your options

Comment: There is another opinion on the topic: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using AS instead of = for column aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)

Comment: @marc_s: Jinx! Guess we're both Aaron Bertrand followers. :-)

Comment: Using '=' instead of 'AS' immediately and completely makes your SQL non-portable.  It will only ever work on MS SQL Server.  Microsoft will be happy with you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - You pointed out yourself that `AS` is also non-portable. Every platform has made its own contributions to SQL, and you'll be hard pressed to design a database and write SQL for it that is perfectly portable across SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, and PostgreSQL without modification.

Comment: @NickChammas: Jonathan pointed out that AS is not supported in a table alias, not a column alias.  AS in a column alias is part of the standard SQL92 grammar.

Comment: @qes - Using `AS` to denote a table alias is also part of [the SQL92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt). See section `6.3  <table reference>`, on pages 118-119.

Answer (score 10):

The two are equivalent for most purposes.  I prefer the explicit AS notation.

One reason why I use the AS form is because, in the DBMS I use mainly, it provides a measure of protection against new keywords appearing on system upgrades.  That is:

```
SELECT TestColumn KeyWord
```

where 'KeyWord' becomes a keyword in a future release can cause problems, whereas in the particular system, using:

```
SELECT TestColumn AS KeyWord
```

remains valid.

I recently learned (was told) that Oracle does not support AS in table aliases.

```
FROM TableName T1     -- OK in Oracle
FROM TableName AS T1  -- Not OK in Oracle
```

If that is accurate (I've not validated it), then I regard that AS a bug.

It's your choice, though; the two notations are equivalent.

Comment: +1 and yes Oracle doesn't allow `FROM TableName AS T1`. Given that they don't claim 100% standards performance I don't share your view that it should be called a "bug" though :-)

Comment: @JackDouglas: For me, it is a hypothetical issue, and therefore a hypothetical bug (because I don't get to work hands-on with Oracle).  But it would infuriate the living daylights out of me if I needed to use Oracle.  However, one adapts as necessary.  Thanks for confirming what I remembered being told!

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the second one (using "AS"). If it works either way, just use what you prefer and use it consistently.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't make any difference which you use, just stick with it. I prefer `AS` personally, it's more specific-feeling.

Answer (score 3):

Both should work.  Pick whatever you prefer, or whatever you feel adds to readability of the query.  I personally usually alias with "AS", just a smidge more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

More specifically, it depends on the coding standards for the environment in which you are working. Regardless of personal preference you may have to adapt your style to align with the coding standards of the group or team which you are working on.

It is more important that your SQL has the same look and feel as the rest of the SQL around it to facilitate in testing and debugging of your code when it is handed off to the testing team and ultimately the operations and maintenance team in production.